# Repeat header row after each row in a repeater

Tags: asp.net, header, repeater, tableheader

How can I repeat the header row after each row of Repeator?

Sample Code:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="repeter1" runat="server">
                    <HeaderTemplate>
                        <table style="table-layout: fixed; width:100%;" >
                            <tr>
                                <th>Column 1</th>
                                <th>Column 2 </th>
                                <th>Column 3</th>
                            </tr>
                    </HeaderTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <asp:Label ID="lbl1" runat="server"><%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "column1")%></asp:Label></td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:Label ID="lbl2" runat="server"><%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "column2")%></asp:Label></td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:Label ID="lbl3" runat="server"><%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "column3")%></asp:Label></td>
                        </tr>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        </table>
                    </FooterTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
```

can someone please let me know how to put header after each row of result in repeater?

Comment: Do you mean you want the "Column 1" "Column 2" & "Column 3" after (before?) each actual data row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a repeater, you've got a **HeaderTemplate** and that content is generated once, then you have the **ItemTemplate**, that's generated as many times as there are rows of data, and finally you have the **FooterTemplate**, that is also generated once, after all the rows are done.

To have your "header row" repeated before each content row, simply move your "header" `<tr>` into the `<ItemTemplate>`:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="repeter1" runat="server">
   <HeaderTemplate>
      <table style="table-layout: fixed; width:100%;" >
   </HeaderTemplate>
   <ItemTemplate>
         <tr>
           <th>Column 1</th>
           <th>Column 2</th>
           <th>Column 3</th>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td>
              <asp:Label ID="lbl1" runat="server"><%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "column1")%></asp:Label></td>
           <td>
              <asp:Label ID="lbl2" runat="server"><%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "column2")%></asp:Label></td>
           <td>
              <asp:Label ID="lbl3" runat="server"><%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "column3")%></asp:Label></td>
         </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
      </table>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```